# Store data frame each day

Tags: ios, swift

I make an application which receives data via bluetooth. I would like to store this data received at regular intervals to make a history and store it in the application.

I would like to know what to use (Core Data, UserDefaults, ...) ?
Thanks

Comment: What's the size and structure of received data?

Comment: I receive an array of ten UInt8 each seconds but i need to store only when application is launched otherwise I think it will do a lot of data to store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on amount of data but mostly what you want to do with that data.

Core data will take most of time to implement but you can do a whole lot of things with that data. You can search and filter items for instance by date and even put them into sections. `NSFetchedResultsController` can be very helpful here.

User defaults are probably not very appropriate as they are designed to hold small (or at least finite) amount of data variables like some settings, flags...

The other that comes to mind is simply saving them into file. Probably the easiest would be using JSON. `JSONSerialization` should be able to encode or decode your data from concrete objects to `Data` and back. Also there are some nice tools now that can greatly speed up the process. Check into [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types). `Data` in the end can be saved directly into files which may then be created in documents directory of your application.

You should evaluate how will these data be accessed. If you are targeting for instance showing charts on monthly, daily and hourly basics, have ability to remove entries and such then I would go with Core Data. If you just need to open some old logs and look into them then saving to disk is probably a more fitting solution.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I think I will use files solution !